# Clear filter in ag-grid on tab changed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ag-grid

I have default filter and custom filter for `ag-grid` . I want to clear filter on tab change.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        rowData: null,
        angularCompileRows: true,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableColResize: true,
        enableFilter: true,
        rowHeight: 35,
        rowSelection: 'single',
        onSelectionChanged: onSelectionChanged,
        isExternalFilterPresent: isExternalFilterPresent,
        doesExternalFilterPass: doesExternalFilterPass,
        overlayLoadingTemplate: '<span class="ag-overlay-loading-center">Please wait while your rows are loading</span>',
        overlayNoRowsTemplate: '<span style="    transform: translateY(-50%);opacity: 0.25;font-size: 3em;">No data available</span>'
    };
```

I tried this but it's not working

```
    $scope.gridOptions.api.resetFilters();
$scope.gridOptions.api.destroyFilter();
```

Please suggest any method to do reset all filters of `ag-grid`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.gridOptions.api.setFilterModel(null);
$scope.gridOptions.api.onFilterChanged();
```

Comment: Do we have any options to get the column name on filter changed?.Filter model is getting empty while clearing the filter. Any possible way to get column name on clearing?